# Handling authentication related intermediate redirects with ApacheHttpClient

Tags: java, jsp, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to open this uri

```
https://some-host/a/meta?  (this url is passed to proxi.jsp page)
```

.. but it redirects to authentication service (on https) which popups a box for username and password...and if on browser.. it then needs you to key-in the credentials.. and it then comes back to the first link i was trying to open and shows the content... so i want to know that when this intermediate redirect to authentication service happens.. how do i enter my username and password to that popup through code.. I am trying to use apache HttpClient to do this...

This is my proxi.jsp code which is making the request..

```
<%@ page language="java" import="
java.util.Collection,
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient,
org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials,
org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope,
org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod"
contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%
try {
String a_Url = request.getParameter( "url" ) ;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getState().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, "realm"),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test", "pass")
);

GetMethod get = new GetMethod(a_Url);
get.setDoAuthentication( true );
try {
    int status = client.executeMethod( get );
    out.println(status + "\n" + get.getResponseBodyAsString());
} finally {
     get.releaseConnection();
}
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}   

%>
```

And this is the error I am getting:-

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.InvalidRedirectLocationException: Invalid redirect
 location: https://login.xyz.com/13/smt
d.scc?TYPE=16&REALM=-SM-Documentum%20
uGVx6wOk1daI3&TARGET=-http%3A%2F%2Fsome-hid%3D10
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.processRedirectRespo
nse(HttpMethodDirector.java:619)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMe
thodDirector.java:179)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.jav
a:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.jav
a:323)
        at org.apache.jsp.proxi_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.proxi_jsp:64)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
.java:389)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:4
86)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511
)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:3
90)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav
a:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:1
82)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:7
65)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)

        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(Normal
RewrittenUrl.java:213)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.j
ava:171)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:14
5)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewri
ter.java:92)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewrit
eFilter.java:381)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1157)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainI
nvocation.java:67)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilte
rPipeline.java:122)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:110)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:3
88)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav
a:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:1
82)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:7
65)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)

        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHand
lerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.
java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:1
52)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:53
6)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpCo
nnection.java:915)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:539)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:405)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.ja
va:409)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.j
ava:582)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException: Invalid query
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.parseUriReference(URI.java:2049)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.<init>(URI.java:147)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.processRedirectRespo
nse(HttpMethodDirector.java:601)
        ... 44 more
```

And If I try to paste this url

```
https://login.xyz.com/9]&AUTHREASON=0&METHOD=GET@Name
```

back on the browser then I get a pop up window for authentication and If I write my username and password in that window then I get the actual content that I am looking for. 
Is there any header that I have to pass in proxi.jsp page. Because passing username and password in the page is not the best way to do it..Or any other way. Any suggestions will be appreciated..

Comment: Do you know if it is Basic Auth that is being used?

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using HttpClient 3.1, since my testing indicates that HttpClient 3.0 is fine with that URL. HttpClient 3.1, however throws an error when it gets to the `[` in the query string. Why that is the case I am not sure. According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) both `[` and `]` should be allowed. Looking at the [`URI`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/httpclient/URI.java.html#851) source in HttpClient 3.1 it doesn't include those characters for some reason. This is possibly a bug in that version I would say. That being said, I don't think there is any work going into HttpClient 3.x since 4.x is now the focus.

Comment: @laz, I am using HttpClient 4.1.1 not the HttpClient 3.1. Then why is it happening with HttpClient 4.1.1

Comment: @laz, In my maven dependencies, I am having `commons-httpclient-3.1.jar , httpclient-4.1.1.jar, httpcore-4.1.jar` So that is fine?? or something is wrong.. and commons-httpclient-3.1.jar is interfering with 4.1.1 or that is fine..??

Comment: Those classes from the `org.apache.commons.httpclient` are from the old 3.x library. For 4.1.1 you would import items from `org.apache.http` such as `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`.

Comment: You should only need `httpclient-4.1.1.jar` I think.

Comment: @laz, so how do I remove this commons-httpclient-3.1.jar. If I right click on this then I am not getting anything to remove it.. or should I go and remove it from lib directory??

Comment: @RaihanJamal let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1032/discussion-between-laz-and-raihan-jamal)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the site uses Basic Authentication -- can you try the following where test is the user name and pass is the password for the site that you are entering.

```
https://test:pass@some-host/a/getmeta?id=10
```

Comment: but that is not the best way to do it.. right.. still m getting the same error back..Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ok. I guess its not basic auth then. Sorry about that

Comment: @Raihan Looks like the site uses SiteMinder, i know you are in java but you can take a look at this article -- i know little about siteminder but this article looks like it might be useful to you. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SiteminderHttpWebRequest.aspx

Comment: thanks for replying. Any code in java will be of great help to me.. As I have to dig into that..

Answer (score 0):

According to the Exception the URL location `https://login.host.com/` is reachable.
And the URL written in the last is pointing to different location.

```
https://login.host.com/ --> Unreachable
https://login.somehost.com/ --> Reachable
```

Both the URLs are not equal

Comment: So whats the result. Have you get your desired output?

Comment: Yes now they are same. But still my answer is same. The place where the code is running, the location is not valid.